# How to require rakefile for unit testing the tasks in Ruby (not rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a spec that looks like this for testing the Rakefile tasks:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Rakefile' do
  describe "redeem_orders" do
    context "with default paths" do
      subject { Rake::Task['redeem_orders'].invoke }

      let(:input_path) { "./public/input/orders.csv" }
      let(:output_path) { "./public/output/redemptions.csv" }

      it "transfer the data from input to output path" do
        expect(DataController).to receive(:transfer).with(
          input_path: input_path,
          output_path: output_path,
          input_format: kind_of(Proc),
          output_format: kind_of(Proc)
        )

        subject
      end
    end

    context "with different paths" do
      subject { Rake::Task['redeem_orders'].invoke(some_new_input_path, some_new_output_path) }

      let(:some_new_input_path) { "./some/new/path/orders.csv" }
      let(:some_new_output_path) { "./some/new/path/redemptions.csv" }

      it "transfer the data from input to output path" do
        expect(DataController).to receive(:transfer).with(
          input_path: some_new_input_path,
          output_path: some_new_output_path,
          input_format: kind_of(Proc),
          output_format: kind_of(Proc)
        )

        subject
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How do I actually require the Rakefile? Currently these tasks aren't found. What's the best way to do this? I can't seem to require the `Rakefile`. When I put `require 'Rakefile'` on top, it fails to find the file. What can I do? Is `require` appending an `.rb` or something at the end of this file?

this is my tree:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Rakefile
├── Readme.md
├── lib
│   ├── chocolates
│   │   └── chocolate_totals_calculator.rb
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── csv_processor.rb
│   │   ├── data_controller.rb
│   │   ├── data_processor.rb
│   │   ├── file_processor_factory.rb
│   │   └── file_type_processor.rb
│   ├── errors
│   │   └── errors.rb
│   └── promotions
│       └── chocolates
│           ├── chocolate_promotion.rb
│           ├── dark_chocolate_promotion.rb
│           ├── milk_chocolate_promotion.rb
│           ├── promotions_factory.rb
│           ├── sugar_free_chocolate_promotion.rb
│           └── white_chocolate_promotion.rb
├── public
│   ├── input
│   │   └── orders.csv
│   └── output
│       └── redemptions.csv
└── spec
    ├── chocolates
    │   └── chocolate_totals_calculator_spec.rb
    ├── data
    │   ├── csv_processor_spec.rb
    │   ├── data_controller_spec.rb
    │   ├── data_processor_spec.rb
    │   ├── file_processor_factory_spec.rb
    │   └── file_type_processor_spec.rb
    ├── fixtures
    │   └── test_orders.csv
    ├── integration
    │   └── orders_to_redemptions_spec.rb
    ├── promotions
    │   └── chocolates
    │       ├── chocolate_promotion_spec.rb
    │       ├── dark_chocolate_promotion_spec.rb
    │       ├── milk_chocolate_promotion_spec.rb
    │       ├── promotions_factory_spec.rb
    │       ├── sugar_free_chocllate_promotion_spec.rb
    │       └── white_chocolate_promotion_spec.rb
    ├── rakefile_spec.rb
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

Comment: Where is your Rakefile relative to the spec file?

Comment: Agreed, we'll need to see your directory structure.
The `tree` command can probably get you this easily if your machine has it.

Comment: @kennycoc edited!

Comment: Looks like `require '../Rakefile'` should work